# How can enable the DEBUG privilege for a user in Active Directory?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

Using Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2, how can I give a user the DEBUG privilege?  There doesn't seem to be an option anywhere in "Active Directory Users and Computers".

Is there another tool I should be using to toggle this for AD users?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about assigning the [SeDebugPrivilege](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530716(VS.85).aspx) right to user accounts throgh Group Policy?

If so, you're talking about using the "User Rights Assignment" functonality of Group Policy (see [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776977(WS.10).aspx) for an example of such a scenario).

Otherwise I'm not sure what you're looking for.